# Find out how much electricity is being fed through my charging adapter?

Tags: kernel, power-management, laptop, thinkpad, acpi

I am not an electrician, so I am not sure how to ask this, whether I need to refer to voltage, or watts, or something out.
In lamens terms, I am wondering how much electricity is currently being fed to my laptop through my charging adapter.

The reason why I want to know this is because sometimes my laptop internal battery is charging, and other times it is discharging while plugged in. I'd like to know what the values are at either point, and discover if this is something I can adjust with the kernel, to fix any issues that may be related to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several tools for checking the power status of your computer.

You can try installing `upower` if you haven't got it already. Then run:

```
upower -e
```

This will display the detected devices. Then run the information mode on the battery according to the device you have available:

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

This will give you the following information. You can look at the `energy-rate`

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SMP
  model:                DELL 1P6KD5A
  serial:               2206
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 04 Jan 2021 11:56:02 PM CET (102 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              38.5434 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         38.5434 Wh
    energy-full-design:  83.9952 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.0114 W
    voltage:             12.382 V
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            45.8876%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'
```